# Cant get $_POST values from multiple forms

Tags: php, forms, post, if-statement

i got a bit of a problem, as you guys can see in my code, i got a foreach looping through my img folder, showing all the images, well i left out the proper styling of the images, since the problem is the form inside every image.

i need to get the value from the radio input, so i can tell my other script to select all the info from the DB where the ID has the same value as the input.

and i needed a if statement so that if nothing is set i can show something saying you need to select a radio before you can listen to any stations.

but my if statement keeps showing 'error', even tho i click on the buttons

i hope anyone could help me out :)

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRadio')):
    $test = $_POST['radio'];
    echo $test;
else:
    echo 'error';
endif;

foreach(glob('img/radios/big/*.png') as path):
    printf('
        <form method="post">
            <input class="hidden" type="text" name="radio"  value="1">
            <input type="submit" name="submitRadio" value="Go!">
        </form>
    ');
endforeach;
```

after doing what GolezTrol told me to do:

```
<div class="row text-center">
              <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM radio";

                $stmt = $Db->dbh->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                if(isset($_POST['submitRadio'])):
                  $test = $_POST['submitRadio'];
                  echo $test;
                else:
                  echo 'error';
                endif;

              ?>

              <form method="post">

              <?
                foreach($result as $radio):

                  printf('

                  <button type="submit"
                          name="submitRadio"
                          value="'.$radio['id'].'">
                     Go!
                  </button>

                  ');
              ?>

              </form>
```

Comment: do var_dump($_POST) on top to see what is being posted from the form

Comment: HTML forms basics 101: Only _checked_ radio buttons are included in the submitted data. Yours are not checked – so no name=value pair gets send for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed my previous solution. I only just saw that you have no actual radio button but hidden elements, so basically the buttons are the radios. 
That changes it a little bit because you actually have the alternative suggestion I proposed earlier: The buttons themselves work as radiobuttons that immediately post the chosen option.

To solve your issue, you can use a `button` instead of an `input` for submitting the form. In a button, you can make the caption and the value differ from each other, so you can just put the `id` (or filename, or whatever you need) in the value of the button and don't need the hidden input at all. The content of the button tag is the caption it gets, so the code can look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['selectedFile')):
    $test = $_POST['selectedFile'];
    echo $test;
else:
    echo 'error';
endif;

?><form method="post"><? // Open the form outside of the loop

foreach(glob('img/radios/big/*.png') as path):
    // Not sure what you want to do here. Put the filename instead of 
    // "1" in the value?
    $filename = basename($path, '.png');
    ?>
      <button type="submit" 
              name="selectedFile" 
              value="<?=$filename?>">
         Go!
      </button>
    <?
endforeach;

?></form><? // Close the form
```

In this example I've pulled the form tags out of the loop, because strictly you only need one form. But since there are now no radiobuttons at all, you could also have one form per button. It would still work.

By the way, I saw you mentioned a database in your comment. Of course I didn't take that into account, since you didn't mention that in the question. Anyway, it shouldn't change the basic concept, only the way the 'value' is determined.

Comment: ill give that a go now, btw do i need to place my script beneath the form or above or doesnt that matter at all ?

Comment: You mean the 'if' check? Doesn't matter much, although I can imagine if a value is posted you don't want to show the form at all. In that case, I would say above, so you can skip generating the form.

Comment: well you are working with filenames, but im gonna work with a DB and ID's i will foreach the whole db, ill get my db going first i guess :)

Comment: Wow, I only just see that you have no radio button but hidden elements, so basically the buttons are the radios. That changes it a little bit because you actually have the alternative suggestion I proposed. What I would change is to put the value (the filename?) If you give me a moment, I'll work that out in a code example too.

Comment: i got this working, but now the page refreshes, thats not rly what i want, since it hops back to the top of the page, any solutions to that ? see the edit of my post

Comment: I got some ideas (basically: Javascript/Ajax), but that's a whole other subject. Better to round-up this question and (if you need help) start a new one, otherwise it will become messy.

Answer (score 0):

First, the value code in radio tag is always 1. So if any radio button is selected, you will always gets 1. Instead the value clause should have the filename. So you get to know which image (radio button) is selected.

For none of the image (radio button) selected, you may use

```
if (!isset($_POST['radio']))<br>{<br>//php code }
```