# Stop form from refreshing on submit

Tags: php, forms, post, if-statement, refresh

I've got this problem that the form refreshes on submit, i dont want it to refresh but i do want it to submit. any of you know what i could do ?

click this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830695/cant-get-post-values-from-multiple-forms/28830782#28830782) to an older post about this.

```
<form method="post" id="radioForm">

<?
foreach($result as $radio):

    printf('

        <button type="submit"
            href="#radio"
            name="submitRadio"
            value="'.$radio['id'].'">
            Go!
        </button>

    ');
endforeach;
?>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#radioForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        data:{submitRadio:[radiovalue]},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
            /* write your code for what happens when the form submit */
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax form submit.

Comment: im not familiar with ajax or Js so if you could help me out on that one that would be awesome

Comment: What do you want to happen on submit?

Comment: I dont think It is possible without using ajax or js.

Comment: to post the value wich is the ID of that specific radio, so i can load it into my script for the player, but not on refresh

Comment: got any websites or just a example for me ? Vegeta

Answer (score 0):

use ajax like this of jquery

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url:'index.php',
    data:{submitRadio:[radiovalue]},
    type:'POST',
    success:function(response) {
        /* write your code for what happens when the form submit */
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the form name should be 'form' as of your question

Comment: sorry i gave my form the id radioForm

Comment: remove the square bracket... that is only for your references and try

Answer (score 0):

Use submit() handler and pass the value of your button to your other script

First set the id on the form.

```
<form method="post" id="formId">
```

Then bind a listener

```
$( "#formId" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //This is where you put code to take the value of the radio button and pass it to your player.
});
```

To use this you need jQuery.

You can read more about this handler here: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of a HTML `<form>` on submit, it makes the browser `POST` data to the target location specified in the `action` attribute and loads the result of that processing to the user.

If you want to submit the form and `POST` the values behind the scenes without reloading the page, you have to disable the default behavior (the form submit) and employ the use of `AJAX`.  This kind of functionality is available readily within various JavaScript libraries, such as a common one called `jQuery`.

Here is the documentation for jQuery's AJAX functionality http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

There are lots of tutorials on the interwebs that can introduce you to the basic use of jQuery (Including the library into your HTML pages) and also how to submit a form via AJAX.

You will need to create a PHP file that can pick up the values that are posted as a result of the AJAX requests (such as commit the values to a database).  The file will need to return values that can be picked up within your code so that you know if the request was un/successful.  Often the values returned are in the format `JSON`.

There are lots of key words in this answer that can lead you on your way to AJAX discovery.  I hope this helps!